# Interactively writing/reading from an external program

Tags: python, subprocess

*Backstory: I'm pretty new to Python, but fairly experienced in Perl.  I'm trying to diversify my scripting portfolio in the sysadmin-activities area.*

I'm attempting to dynamically communicate with an external process from my python script.

What I want to do is:

- Call an executable (lets call it "cli")
- Write a line to cli
- Read the response back internally
- Iterate through the response, one by one, and write another line to the CLI
- Print the response from the cli back to the console

What I'm hoping this will yield is:

```
(spawn process) /usr/local/bin/cli
-> show listofobjects
<- (read back list of objects internally)
-> (one by one, write a line to the cli for each of the list of objects)
-> get objectname modifiedtime
<- (print response from above command)
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import shlex, subprocess, re

clicmd = "/usr/local/bin/cli -s 10.1.213.226 -n Administrator -p password"
cliargs = shlex.split(clicmd)
cliproc = subprocess.Popen(cliargs,
                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                      )

tmpclicmd = "LIST objects OUTPUT csv NAME"
cliret = cliproc.communicate(input=tmpclicmd)[0]
regex = re.compile('^\".*')

for line in cliret.split('\n'):
    if regex.match(line):
        procline = line.replace('"','')
        if 'NAME' not in procline:
            clideets = subprocess.Popen(cliargs,
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                       )
            clideetscmd = 'modify objects ' + procline
            clideets.communicate(input=clideetscmd)
            clideetscmd = 'list objectdetails'
            clideetsresp = clideets.communicate(input=clideetscmd)[0]

            print clideetsresp;
```

I'm probably going about this in the completely wrong way.  Do I have to spawn a new Popen for every step of the way?  How could I do this better? (another module, etc).  At the end of the day, I can't have the cli close on me, which Popen seems to do after each step of the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And ... what's your question?

Comment: Does your code work? Not work? Produce errors? Hang?

Comment: General "Pythonic" tweaks: Swap `if regex.match(line) is not None:` for `if regex.match(line):` and swap `procline = line.replace("\"","")` for `procline = line.replace('"','')` and swap `if re.match('NAME', procline) is None:` for `if 'NAME' not in procline:`

Comment: Added more specific questions at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is not necessary to start a new process (using `Popen`) for every interaction. You do though, when you use [`communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) for sending data to the process, because, as the documentation states:

   > Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
   >   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate.**

   Instead, simply write to `cliproc.stdin` and read from `cliproc.stdout`:

   ```
   cliproc.stdin.write("LIST objects OUTPUT csv NAME")
   cliret = cliproc.stdout.readline()
   ```

   The process keeps alive this way.
2. I don't know why you use the `shlex` module here:

   > ```
   > clicmd = "/usr/local/bin/cli -s 10.1.213.226 -n Administrator -p password"
   > cliargs = shlex.split(clicmd)
   > ```

   The built-in [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method will do fine:

   ```
   clicmd = "/usr/local/bin/cli -s 10.1.213.226 -n Administrator -p password"
   cliargs = clicmd.split()
   ```

   Or you can just write the resulting list yourself:

   ```
   cliargs = ["/usr/local/bin/cli", "-s", "10.1.213.226",
              "-n", "Administrator", "-p", "password"]
   ```
3. You don't need a semicolon here:

   > ```
   > print clideetsresp;
   > ```

Comment: `cliproc.stdout.read()` will also wait until end-of-file. The pipes do not distinguish message parts by themsleves. You can use `readline()` instead of `read()` to get the data line by line.

Comment: It may also be necessary to write an additional `\n` (or `print` instead of `write`) and `flush()`.

Comment: The shlex was just from some sample piece of code I was reading somewhere.  No actual reason why it's there over the builtin.  As for the semicolon, that's just my perl showin'.